# Count all files on SQL

Tags: sql

I've a table alumnos in wich 'notas' stocks student's notes.
Like:
    DNI(1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666).
    NOTA(5, 9, 2, 5, 1).

I've other table with subjects, dni etc...

How can I know on SQL how many subjects have at least 1 suspended note (<5)?

I've the rest of code, but I cannot know how to get the subjects with at least 1 note below 5.

Comment: Please explain your data definitions explicitly, the relevant `CREATE TABLE` statements, for example, and some sample data for the relevant tables. The answer will probably involve `group by students having notes < 5`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your db version is Oracle 11g,

```
select * from TABLE
where  regexp_count(notas,',') between 1 and 5
```